# What is the best way to display and interact with a skill tree

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to create an interface that is similar to the interface on this website for the skill tree: http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree. What is the best way to go about doing this and have the same or similar user interaction. ie. you click on a node and it activate or deactivates it. The movement of the tree and zooming on it would be nice as well. Would like to try to stay away from webView as I am thinking about features I want to add. Thanks in advance just want to see what a good way to do this is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webView and have almost a copy-paste of the presented webpage html source and load it.

However with native components you can have better performance, but it will "not a copy"

Native componets: 
[IIViewDeckController for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller)

[iHasApp for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ihasapp)
[iHasApp for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ghsidebarnav)

There are more on that side. Consider a combination of they,

Comment: I was hoping to not use a web for performance reasons but if that is the only way I will do it that way.

Comment: And because I wanted to add features to it.

Comment: well, you can have a list and event to it, depends if you need to develop from 0 or you just want to migrate your existing code from web

Comment: It is going to be develop from zilch kinda as the web code was written by the company and I am a player of the game developing a stand alone app.

Comment: added a few link to custom components.